# Excel VBA SQL Server connection timeout

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm going to connect to a SQL Server database from different networks (the server has two network cards) and depending on which network my computer is located in, I need to send a message to the user if the database is unreachable from that network (The user checks a checkbox telling the code which network he/she is on).

I want to set the connection timeout to something less than the default (30 seconds), so that the user does not have to wait the whole timeout period. My problem is that all things I have tried don't work.

This is my rudimentary code:

```
Public Function OpenDatabaseConnection() As Boolean
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    Cn.ConnectionTimeout = 2
    Cn.CommandTimeout = 2
    
    On Error GoTo DBError
    
    If gboolNetworSelectionLocal = True Then
        Cn.Open gstrCONNECTION_STRING_LOCAL
    Else
        Cn.Open gstrCONNECTION_STRING_PUBLIC
    End If
    
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
    
    OpenDatabaseConnection = True
    Exit Function
DBError:
    MsgBox "Database connection attempt failed. Contact your system administrator!", vbExclamation
    OpenDatabaseConnection = False
End Function
```

If anyone has any tips - they are more than welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Connection strings can specify timeouts. You need to override timeout after setting connection string (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/connectionstring-connectiontimeout-and-state-properties-example-vb?view=sql-server-ver15) OR you can add timeout setting to connection string itself (see https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/528938/SQLplusCommandplusexcelplusVBAplustimeout)

Comment: On which line is the error happening? The function name suggests you just want to test connectivity, but it also tries to create a record set and execute SQL against it... so where is `SQLStr` coming from? Could it be the source of the error?

Comment: I tried to set the timeout in the connection string (as you described) but that did not do any difference unfortunately. About the SQLStr variable, that is a global variable in the module in which this function reside. 

SQLStr = "sp_StoredProcedure_GetData" & strVar1 & strVar2

About the error. The error is expected and what I want is to shorten the timeout so that the user doesn't have to wait so long.

Comment: Have you tried setting timeout on the connection object after you assign conn string to it, as per MS article?

Comment: Yes I have but it did not work.

Comment: Can you post your connection string? What provider are you using?

Comment: Public Const gstrCONNECTION_STRING As String = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;Database=[DATABASE];Uid=UserName;Pwd=password"